# Merging JSON arrays using Groovy 2.4

Tags: arrays, json, groovy

I have the below Input JSON for which I am trying to merge the scheduleDetails which has same ID

```
    {"orderLines": [{
            "ID": "001",
            "scheduleDetails": [{
                "address": {
                    "street": [
                        "1234 Unknown blvd001-1"
                    ],
                    "city": "unknown001-1"
                }
            }]
        },
        {
            "ID": "003",
            "scheduleDetails": [{
                "address": {
                    "street": [
                        "1234 Unknown blvd003-1"
                    ],
                    "city": "unknown003-1"
                }
            }]
        },
        {
            "ID": "001",
            "scheduleDetails": [{
                "address": {
                    "street": [
                        "1234 Unknown blvd001-2"
                    ],
                    "city": "unknown001-2"
                }
            }]
        },
        {
            "ID": "002",
            "scheduleDetails": [{
                "address": {
                    "street": [
                        "1234 Unknown blvd002-1"
                    ],
                    "city": "unknown002-1"
                }
            }]
        },
        {
            "ID": "003",
            "scheduleDetails": [{
                "address": {
                    "street": [
                        "1234 Unknown blvd003-2"
                    ],
                    "city": "unknown003-2"
                }
            }]
        }
    ]
}
```

I am trying to use the below Groovy 2.4 code to achieve it

```
import java.util.Properties;
import java.io.InputStream;
import groovy.json.JsonSlurper;
import groovy.json.JsonOutput;
import com.boomi.execution.ExecutionUtil;

logger = ExecutionUtil.getBaseLogger();
for( int i = 0; i < dataContext.getDataCount(); i++ ) {
   InputStream is = dataContext.getStream(i);   
    Properties props = dataContext.getProperties(i);
    def slurper = new JsonSlurper();
    def jsonObj = slurper.parse(is);
   for( int j = 0; j < jsonObj.orderLines.size(); j++ ) {
        fulfillmentLineIdJ = jsonObj.orderLines.getAt(j).get("ID").toString();
        for (int k = 0; k < jsonObj.orderLines.size(); k++ ) {
           fulfillmentLineIdK = jsonObj.orderLines.getAt(k).get("ID").toString();
            if (fulfillmentLineIdJ == fulfillmentLineIdK || fulfillmentLineIdJ == fulfillmentLineIdK.substring(0, fulfillmentLineIdK.length() - 1) )
            {                              
                jsonObj.orderLines.getAt(j).scheduleDetails.add(jsonObj.orderLines.getAt(k).scheduleDetails.getAt(0));                
                jsonObj.orderLines.getAt(j).scheduleDetails.unique();               
                if (fulfillmentLineIdJ == fulfillmentLineIdK.substring(0, fulfillmentLineIdK.length() - 1)) {
                   jsonObj.orderLines.remove(k);
                    k--;
               } 
            }
        }   
    } 
    int m = 0;
    int n = 0;  
    while ( m < jsonObj.orderLines.size() ) {
       fulfillmentLineIdM = jsonObj.orderLines.getAt(m).get("ID").toString();
       while (n < jsonObj.orderLines.size() - 1) {
          n++;
          fulfillmentLineIdN = jsonObj.orderLines.getAt(n).get("ID").toString();
           if (fulfillmentLineIdM == fulfillmentLineIdN) {
                   jsonObj.orderLines.remove(n);
            }          
        }
       m++;  
    }   
    //Output to stream
    InputStream newIs = new ByteArrayInputStream(JsonOutput.toJson(jsonObj).getBytes());
    dataContext.storeStream(newIs, props);

}
```

The output of the above code is giving the 003 ID repeating as below. The last occurrence of ID 003 is the issue which should not appear in my output.Any inputs to changes in my code is much appreciated.

```
{
    "orderLines": [
        {
            "ID": "001",
            "scheduleDetails": [
                {
                    "address": {
                        "street": [
                            "1234 Unknown blvd001-1"
                        ],
                        "city": "unknown001-1"
                    }
                },
                {
                    "address": {
                        "street": [
                            "1234 Unknown blvd001-2"
                        ],
                        "city": "unknown001-2"
                    }
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "ID": "003",
            "scheduleDetails": [
                {
                    "address": {
                        "street": [
                            "1234 Unknown blvd003-1"
                        ],
                        "city": "unknown003-1"
                    }
                },
                {
                    "address": {
                        "street": [
                            "1234 Unknown blvd003-2"
                        ],
                        "city": "unknown003-2"
                    }
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "ID": "002",
            "scheduleDetails": [
                {
                    "address": {
                        "street": [
                            "1234 Unknown blvd002-1"
                        ],
                        "city": "unknown002-1"
                    }
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "ID": "003",
            "scheduleDetails": [
                {
                    "address": {
                        "street": [
                            "1234 Unknown blvd003-2"
                        ],
                        "city": "unknown003-2"
                    }
                },
                {
                    "address": {
                        "street": [
                            "1234 Unknown blvd003-1"
                        ],
                        "city": "unknown003-1"
                    }
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a job for `groupBy`: first group all order lines with the same
id (this gives you a map from the value of `ID` to a list of order lines
with the ID) then merge all scheduled details per group.  E.g.

```
def data = new groovy.json.JsonSlurper().parse("data.json" as File)

def groupedByID = data.orderLines.groupBy{ 
    it.ID 
}.collect{ 
    [ID: it.key, 
     scheduleDetails: it.value*.scheduleDetails.flatten()] 
}

println(groovy.json.JsonOutput.toJson([orderLines: groupedByID]))
// {
//    "orderLines" : [
//       {
//          "ID" : "001",
//          "scheduleDetails" : [
//             {
//                "address" : {
//                   "city" : "unknown001-1",
//                   "street" : [
//                      "1234 Unknown blvd001-1"
//                   ]
//                }
//             },
//             {
//                "address" : {
//                   "city" : "unknown001-2",
//                   "street" : [
//                      "1234 Unknown blvd001-2"
//                   ]
//                }
//             }
//          ]
//       },
// ...
```